# how can I delete the entries which my mysql query finds?

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

```
SELECT u.name, u.age, u.sex
FROM User u
INNER JOIN (
SELECT age, sex, COUNT(*)
FROM User
GROUP BY age, sex
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
ON temp.age = u.age
AND temp.sex = u.sex
ORDER BY age, sex
```

this query finds all my duplicates in my database, but how can I delete the multiple ones?

Comment: Try searching for mysql delete duplicates. If you cannot find anything you can adapt add sample data as text to the question together with expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `ID` of the row your are selecting only, then put `DELETE` that will delete all row with these selected `ID`.

```
DELETE FROM User u
WHERE u.ID IN
(
    SELECT u.ID
    FROM User u
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT u.ID
        FROM User
        GROUP BY age, sex
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) temp
    ON temp.age = u.age
    AND temp.sex = u.sex
    ORDER BY age, sex
)
```

But I have to advise you that you should change your query as it will erase everything. Your select statement is the same than `SELECT * FROM User` as everything if inner joined. So I guess what you really want is:

```
DELETE FROM User u
WHERE u.ID IN
(
    SELECT u.ID
    FROM User
    GROUP BY age, sex
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```